# Как отображать в ListView для элементов, успешный ли HTTP-запрос или нет?

Tags: android, listview, http, http-status-code-404

Имеется приложение музыкальный онлайн плеер. Элементы берутся из JSON файла, расположенного внутри приложения. Файл имеет вид:

```
    [
  {
    "description": "Описание музыкального файла",
    "iconUrl": "https://www.site.ru/image01.jpg",
    "name": "Music001",
    "genre": "Pop Music",
    "streams": ["http://icecast.radio.ru/music.mp3"]
  }
    ]
```

Элементы строятся списком ListView, по нажатии на какой-либо элемент из списка - начинает играть музыка. Как реализовать следующее:

Отображать сразу на каждом элементе, успешный ли HTTP-запрос к файлу  "http:/ /icecast.radio.ru/music.mp3" или нет и выводить соответствующую вьюшку (например красный и зеленый кружок).

p.s: то есть отображение статуса, доступно ли прослушивание или нет должно выводиться сразу, без нажатия по элементу.

```
public class DirectoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DirectoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static int MODE_DIRECTORY = 0;
    private static int MODE_FAVORITES = 1;
    public boolean colorTitleStation = true;
    public interface Listener {
        void onStationClicked(final Station station);
    }

    private final List<Station> stations = new LinkedList<>();
    private Listener listener;
    private int mode;

    public DirectoryAdapter() {
        stations.addAll(getStations());
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.directory_item_two, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Station station = stations.get(position);
        holder.nameView.setText(String.format("%s",station.getName()));
        holder.genre.setText(String.format("%s", station.getNetwork()));
        holder.descriptionView.setText(String.format("%s", station.getDescription()));

        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(station.getIconUrl()).fit().centerCrop().transform(new Transformation() {
            @Override
            public Bitmap transform(final Bitmap source) {
                PaletteCache.generate(station.getIconUrl(), source);
                return source;
            }

            @Override
            public String key() {
                return station.getIconUrl();
            }
        }).into(holder.iconView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                final Palette palette = PaletteCache.get(station.getIconUrl());
                if (palette == null)
                    return;

                final Palette.Swatch swatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
                if (swatch != null) {

                }

                // ставим цвет заголовка названия станций
                if (!colorTitleStation){
                    if (swatch != null) {
                        holder.nameView.setTextColor(swatch.getRgb());
                        colorTitleStation = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    colorTitleStation = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                if (listener != null)
                    listener.onStationClicked(station);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stations.size();
    }

    private List<Station> getStations() {
        if (mode == MODE_FAVORITES) {
            return Favorites.getFavorites();
        }
        return Directory.getStations();
    }

    public void showFavorites() {
        mode = MODE_FAVORITES;

        updateStations();
    }

    public void showDirectory() {

        mode = MODE_DIRECTORY;
        updateStations();
    }

    public void setListener(final Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    public void filterStations(final String query) {
        List<Station> filteredStations = queryStations(query);
        updateStations(filteredStations);
    }

    public void updateStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
        removeFilteredStations(filteredStations);
        addFilteredStations(filteredStations);
    }

    public void updateStations() {
        updateStations(getStations());
    }

    private void removeFilteredStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
        final Iterator<Station> iterator = stations.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final Station station = iterator.next();
            if (!filteredStations.contains(station)) {
                final int position = stations.indexOf(station);
                iterator.remove();
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addFilteredStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
        for (Station station : filteredStations) {
            if (!stations.contains(station)) {
                final int position = findPosition(station);
                stations.add(position, station);
                notifyItemInserted(position);

            }
        }
    }

    private int findPosition(final Station station) {

        int position = 0;
        while(position < stations.size() && stations.get(position).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(station.getName()) < 0) {
            position++;
        }

        return position;
    }

    private List<Station> queryStations(final String query) {
        final List<Station> filtered = new ArrayList<>();

        final boolean isEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(query);
        for (Station station : getStations()) {
            if (isEmpty || station.matchesQuery(query))
                filtered.add(station);
        }
        return filtered;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView iconView;
        TextView nameView, genre;
        TextView descriptionView;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            iconView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            nameView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            descriptionView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            genre = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        }
    }
}
```

и разметка:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/header_selector_two"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTitle"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Record Megamix" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:text="Загрузка..."
                android:textColor="@color/colorTitle"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                tools:background="@drawable/radiok" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/genre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTitle"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Клубное" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ccc"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Проблема в чем?

Comment: проблема в том, что я не пойму как работать с отдельными элементами в listview которые.. как к ним обратиться и т.д

Comment: Как ты его заполняешь?

Comment: в каком смысле? адаптер есть

Comment: В адаптере и проверяй доступно ли прослушивание

Comment: @Alex78191, легко сказать)) ну допустим проверил я., а как отобразить всё это для каждого элемента ListView ? (то есть например открыл приложение, и список загрузился. У каждого элемента допустим будет сразу зеленая или красная лампочка (вьюшка).

Comment: Не пойму как обратиться к строчке с прямым http адресом медиафайла.

Comment: В смысле обратиться?

Comment: @Антон добавьте разметку элемента, код адаптера и как вы его инициализируете.

Comment: @DeKaNszn, обновил

Comment: Серьёзно? Вы используете адаптер для RecyclerView с ListView? Переделать на RecyclerView пробовали?

Comment: это поможет мне сделать то, что я спросил в вопросе??